# Can we restrict the type be a delegate

Tags: c#, .net

We can restrict the type be the class or struct. Can we strict the type be a delegate?

Comment: You have just tried sub-types of Delegate? Although I would likely use the appropriate signature or Func<...>, etc, if possible.

Comment: @user, are you referring to generic constraints?

Comment: yes, I am referring to generic constraints

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Delegate` is a class, and you would normally be able to specify a non-sealed class as a constraint. However, the language specification specifically excludes `System.Delegate` as a valid constraint in section 10.1.5.

> A *class-type* constraint must satisfy
>   the following rules:
>
> - The type must be a class type.
> - The type must not be sealed.
> - **The type must not be one of the following types: System.Array,
>     System.Delegate, System.Enum, or
>     System.ValueType.**
> - The type must not be object. Because all types derive from object,
>     such a constraint would have no effect
>     if it were permitted.
> - At most one constraint for a given type parameter can be a class type.

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: @user - Not a pretty or stable one. It would likely involve reflection, which removes compile-time safety.

Comment: Amazing! Could you show an example of removing compile-time safety?

Comment: @user, binarycoder's answer shows something you may try. Where it gets dicey is once you've figured out that the input is a delegate, where do you go from there? How many parameters does the delegate expect? Would you use the return value (if any)? I do not have such a code example.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been pointed out, the C# specification does not allow a `Delegate` generic constraint. Nor are `Delegate` subclasses accepted by the compiler as a generic constraint.  The best you can do is test and throw an exception. I will show this with a method, but if this is a generic class, the constructor would be a great place to do the check.

```
public void Foo<T>(T x)
{
    if (x == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("x");

    Delegate d = x as Delegate;
    if (d == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Argument must be of Delegate type.", "x");

    // Use d here.
}
```